# What is the best way to get the most useful output from oprofile?

Tags: c, optimization, oprofile

Using tools such as:

- opreport
- opcontrol
- opannotate

I am starting to use this tool and trying to find the best combinations, examples to get 
the most out of profiling.

Thanks

Comment: The meaning of "best" is always dependent on the meaning of "good", and that is not always obvious what is. Could you describe what good things you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [**KCachegrind**](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) - it's a profile data visualization tool.

**KCachegrind** visualize data files generated by [**Callgrind**](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) profiler tool. But with [conversion scripts](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Converters.html), **KCachegrind** is able to visualize output of other profilers like [**OProfile**](http://oprofile.sf.net/).

When you install KCachegrind using a package manager (yum, apt-get, etc.) you get a tool called [op2calltree](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/op2calltree.1.html) which transforms Oprofile's output to KCachegrind's format.

Answer (score 6):

[gprof2dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot) is the most amazing visualization tool for profile data.

```
opcontrol --shutdown
opcontrol --callgraph=7
opcontrol --image=<abs/path/to/your/execuable>
opcontrol --start

... time passes ...

opcontrol --dump
opreport -c > profile_info.txt
gprof2dot.py -f oprofile --strip profile_info.txt | dot -Tsvg > profile_graph.svg
inkscape profile_graph.svg
```

`gprof2dot`'s `--skew` option is really nice when drilling down the actual problem code.

Remeber you can't set callgraph if you've manually set the event counter to a low number.  Be default the when using the `--callgraph` option the minimum counter is 15 times larger than the one listed in `--list-events`

---

**Edit:** example screenshot:
[image: gprof2dot.py example output]

The resolution is reduced to avoid disclosing confidential data, but you get the idea.

Comment: Do you think it's better than KCachegrind?  Have a screenshot?

Comment: @NathanKidd: I have a more complete answer about gprof2dot here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4453999/28817

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot. Many thanks for the tool!