# Profiler for Solaris SPARC Platform (for C++ applications)

Tags: c++, gcc, profiling, solaris, sparc

Is there a profiler for the Solaris 10 SPARC architecture for the use with c++ applications?
If it matters: We're using gcc for compiling our c++ sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use free Solaris/Oracle Studio which comes with a profiler. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/overview/index.html

Answer (score 2):

If you can't afford Quantify (it's not cheap), then you have the option of RYO using either an intrusive library or using something like [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace).

Also worth checking out this question: [Beyond Stack Sampling: C++ Profilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394606/beyond-stack-sampling-c-profilers)

If you can get hold of [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/profiling-tools.html) - I believe there is a profiler built into that (which uses DTrace underneath, I think)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Rational Quantify, or if you're using gcc, gprof will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you could use [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/), I'd recommend it, but I'm not sure if it's limited to Linux.

But then, there's always the [ugly-duckling method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).