# How to monitor QT signals?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

During debugging, I want to see what's awaits my program's event loop. 
It's probably flooded, and I want to see by what signals, without (manually) adding specific log-message to every Q_EMIT.

Possible solutions might be watching some internal-qt-data structure that contains the events-queue (Is there such thing? how?)

Or  -

Write a log message for every signal emitted (Is that possible?).

Any other ideas?

(QT 4.8 on Windows, using visual studio 2012)

Comment: Do you want to monitor signals or events?

Comment: I want to monitor signals.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalspy.html ?

Comment: Thanks!
but if I understood correctly, QSignalSpy is object specific (and signal specific). I have so many objects emits so many signals that I'll hate do it manually.

Comment: You can run your own event loop instead of application one, with `QEventLoop` - and debug it!

Comment: @Ronen, you might want to look into this approach: http://levelfour.googlecode.com/svn/branches/dev/vd2/GCF/source/menustrip/GenericSignalSpy.cpp

Answer (score 5):

Signals and events are two things that don't have anything to do with each other.

> I want to see what's awaits my program's event loop. It's probably flooded.

First of all, let's get the nomenclature straight:

- an *event queue* is where events are stored until delivery;
- an *event loop* is what drains the event queue and delivers events to `QObjects`,
- an *event flood* happens when, on average, during the delivery of each event there is more than one event added to the queue.

There are two reasons **only** why an event queue might get flooded:

1. It takes too long to process some events (e.g. when your code blocks): the drain rate of the queue is lower than the fill rate due to timing.
2. You're adding more than one event per each event delivered (on average): the fill rate of the queue is higher than the drain rate due to event multiplication - this is completely unrelated to any timing. An apt name for it would be an *event storm*.

To detect code the blocks for too long, you can use [a tool I wrote for another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25118309/1329652).

To know how many events are waiting for any given thread, use the undocumented [`qGlobalPostedEventsCount()`](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication.cpp#L307). You add that to the code of the tool linked-to above.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is sufficient for you but you can try installing [event filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) in between QObjects that implement eventFilter() like this:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    QGraphicsView myView;
    MyWidget()
    {
        myView->installEventFilter(this);
        // incoming events to myView are shown on the standard output
    }
};
```

You can get more creative with this reading the docs.

Comment: Thanks, But I don't want to be object specific. I want to see all my signals and I have to many objects to do it manually.

Comment: You can get all the events if you install the event filter on the QCoreApplication or QApplication object, instead of a QGraphicsView as shown here.

Answer (score 1):

The Qt documentation for [Events and Filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html) states:

> It is also possible to filter all events for the entire application, by installing an event filter on the `QApplication` or `QCoreApplication` object. Such global event filters are called before the object-specific filters. This is very powerful, but it also slows down event delivery of every single event in the entire application.

Therefore, you can create an event filter on the QApplication or QCoreApplication and monitor all events, checking their [`type`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#type).

Alternatively, `QCoreApplication` uses the virtual [`notify`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#notify) function to deliver events to objects. Overriding `QCoreApplication` would allow you to see both the event and QObject to which the event will initially* be delivered.

*Note that events are propagated to parent objects, if the receiving object ignores the event.

If you choose to use `notify`, be aware of the future direction for this function:

> *Future direction: This function will not be called for objects that live outside the main thread in Qt 6. Applications that need that functionality should find other solutions for their event inspection needs in the meantime. The change may be extended to the main thread, causing this function to be deprecated*.