# aggregating of function calls from WPR/xperf profiling data, e.g. KCacheGrind?

Tags: c++, windows, profiling, xperf, windows-performance-analyzer

Is it possible to load [WPR/xperf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh162981.aspx) profiling data into [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html)?  Or is there a way to aggregate function calls in [WPA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448170.aspx) directly?  Or some other tool?  Would the [gprof2dot/graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453999/1007353) route be the best option?

I find WPA useful, but grouping by stack in the "CPU Usage (Sampled)" table doesn't seem to allow sorting by aggregated function call count.  For example, if function `foo` is called equally from 10 different places, it would be hard to identify `foo` as a potential bottleneck since each of the 10 code paths to `foo` will show as 10% or less of the weight.  KCacheGrind solves this problem by allowing you to sort on cumulative time for each function.

How can I sort by cumulative time spent in each function with profiling on Windows, e.g. to identify low level shared functions like malloc as a bottlneck?

Comment: As a side note, how come I can't see *any* reference to malloc in my WPA data?  When I do random pausing with Visual Studio I see plenty of call stacks ending in "msvcr100.dll!malloc()" -- is there a setting on WPR that I need to tick to get this level of granularity?

Comment: Don't look for a particular function. Instead take stack samples and see what lines of code are on them. A profiler that does this is Zoom from rotateright.com, but I and plenty of people feel the manual method performs better. Please take a look at [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25870103/23771).

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: thanks, I actually already had that question with your answer there favorited :) .  Still it seems somewhat opinion based whether or not manual method vs profiling tools is the way to go, and I personally feel that a combination is best, so if anyone knows how to get this WPR tool to give useful aggregated information, I'd appreciate it.  Zoom btw doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: I suppose it seems like only an opinion - programmers aren't used to careful argument. That link shows speedups can be missed by profiler back-ends (*false negatives*). [*This link*](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262) shows why it costs you to ignore false negatives. [*This answer*](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1870/1262) gives a specific example and links to the code. In six stages, over 99.8% of time was trimmed, but any stage skipped costs dearly. That's not an isolated example. That example, and those arguments, are real - not opinion.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: thanks for that summary.  You have convinced me now.  I'll stop wasting time with profilers and just stick to debuggers, random pausing, and maybe a logging statement every once in a while.

Comment: I don't want to preach. It's just math and experimentation. You can see for yourself.